# Unable to mount 215 GB Filesystem

Tags: hibernate

I have two OS in same laptop: one is Windows 8 and other is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My installation went fine and Ubuntu works fine. I have two hard drives in my Ubuntu they are 201 GB, and 215 GB. The problem is when I try to open my 215 GB drive I am getting error as:

> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 14: Windows is hibernated,
> refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
> The NTFS partition is hibernated. Please resume and shutdown Windows
> properly, or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option, or
> mount the volume read-write with the 'remove_hiberfile' mount option.
> For example type on the command line:
>
> ```
> mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /media/F44EC8724EC82F64
> ```

I have googled and found that I should use:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /media/F44EC8724EC82F64
```

I can open my drive when I type that command, but the problem is when i restart the system and try to open the same 215 GB drive again I am getting same problem.

Is there any permanent way of solving this problem, instead of running that command everytime when I start Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you *do* what the error message told you to do, that is **boot windows, shut is down normally (no hibernate)** and try the mount again on Ubuntu?

Comment: I believe Win 8 hibernates as default in order to boot quicker, part of it's hybrid shut down.